# Ctrl + F4 opening tty in lenovo g400s

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, tty

I've just installed my lenovo g400s with Ubuntu 14.04 64bit. The problem is when I want to close tab by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f4</kbd>, it open tty and I cannot go back to desktop although I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>/<kbd>F8</kbd>. How to resolve this problem?

And one more thing, I want to make <kbd>Fn</kbd> key usable, because it's no need to press <kbd>Fn</kbd> key to use special function in <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> now. Thank you all.

Comment: Check if your Alt key isn't logically stuck [http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=848755](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=848755)

Answer (score 2):

I've solved my problem. Just turn off hotkeys in BIOS fix all the problem.